# how to replace leading zero from input field instantly whenever onfocusout from input field?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function fieldValidate(){
            let text = document.getElementById('fname').value;
            text = text.replace(/^0+/, '')
        }
</script>


Id: <input type="Number" id="fname" onfocusout="fieldValidate()">
```

Input field value is not changing, it not replacing value exm.. 09 to 9 in input field inside. but replace value is showing in alert() messege.

Comment: 09 technically isn't a number, set your type to text

Comment: @Liam: Chrome lets you type `09` into a number field, FYI.

Comment: According to the spec this should be a [floating point number](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float) which doesn't actually say anything about leading zeros. Still feels wrong to me though and I wouldn't be surprised if it was inconsistent

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
let text = document.getElementById('fname').value;
```

you get the **value** of the `value` property and copy it into `text`. Changing `text` afterward (replacing its value with a new value) has no effect whatsoever on the copy of that value in the `value` property.

Assign back to the `value` property:

```
function fieldValidate(){
    let field = document.getElementById('fname');
    field.value = field.value.replace(/^0+/, '');
}
```

Gratuitous example:

```js
function fieldValidate(){
    var field = document.getElementById('fname');
    field.value = field.value.replace(/^0+/, '');
}
```

```html
Id: <input type="Number" id="fname" onfocusout="fieldValidate()">
```

---

Side note: Unless you're transpiling (which is wonderful), you'll still need to use `var` rather than `let` if this is for use on the general web, to allow for older browsers.

Side note 2: Rather than using `onxyz`-attribute-style handlers, consider using modern event handling for hooking up event handlers.

Comment: Is the use of `parseInt)` a possible alternative way?

Comment: @reporter: You could do that (ignoring engines that will freak out on the leading `0` and assume octal -- hopefully those are few and far between now). But the OP's regex is simple and straightforward.